# How to programmatically detect workitem changed type Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I have a custom field and custom control extension on the Bug and Product Backlog item template.  The value of that field becomes invalid if workitem type changes from Bug to PBI and vice versa.  How can I force the user to select a new value?

Option #1: Allow to provide a list of valid values in the Bug & PBI template and template validation will do the job of notifying the user.

Option #2: I could issue a WorkItemFormService.seterror to force the user to change the value. But I don't see an event in the workitem extension that allows me to detect that the workitem type has changed.

Option #3:  Clear the field when workitem type changes, since I have a rule that says the field cannot be empty. However, this is not an option on the process template rules.

Option #4: Is there a known field that changes when workitem type changes that I can use as "when field x changes, clear the value of field y" rule in the process template? (since I have a rule that says the field cannot be empty. )

Other options?

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Manela [MSFT] answered this in the developercommunity.visualstudio.com

*If you listen for the change field events, you will get a event that just shows that the work item type field has changed
You can see an example of listening here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/work-item-form/workItemNotifications.html*

My code now:

```
onFieldChanged: (args: ExtensionContracts.IWorkItemFieldChangedArgs) => {
if (args.changedFields["System.WorkItemType"] !== undefined) {
//WorkItemType is changing. Clear out our custom field ...
}
//...
}
```